# "And" or "with" when comparing

Tags: word-choice, british-english

If one were to try and compare mixed food with food and a side which would you use? For example, what is the difference between "Green Salad **with** Dressing" and "Green Salad **and** Dressing" and which one would you use to imply the dressing was on the side?

Comment: Is this only about food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of salad and the competence/preferences of whoever prepared it, the dressing might already be mixed or not. In the case of a "green salad", for example, I think it would be straightforward incompetence to serve this mixed. But I don't think it's meaningful to distinguish between *with* and *and* in this context. Neither word implies anything about how it would actually be served.

If you *really* didn't want them mixed, you'd be safest actually specifying that, for example:

**Salad with a dressing served separately**

Comment: Well, depending on the salad you would never normally dress it (unless it's bound by dressing) before it reaches the table.  So I have edited my question to be more specific to Green Salads which one should never dress before they reach the table.  I hope this clarifies it so that "with" and "and" can mean different things but I don't know if it will, worth a try.
<br /><br />
Note: There are more reasons why a chef would never normally dress greens but I'm sure you already know all these reasons so I left them out.

Comment: @Jordon Bedwell: If the menu had the same salad **with** and **and** dressing as separate items, with nothing else to clarify, I would think the place was a bit too 'precious' for me, so I'd eat elsewhere. I would have been there to eat, not to wrestle with someone's bizarre notions of semantic distinctions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know a prescriptive rule that explains which to use when, so I'll go through some examples and hopefully some sort of guide will appear.

> Green Salad with Dressing

Dressing is already on the salad

> Green Salad and Dressing

Dressing is already on the salad

---

> Chips with mayo

Mayo is on the side

> Chips and mayo

Mayo is on the side

---

> Burger and fries

fries are on the side

> Burger with fries

fries are on the side

---

> Fruit with salad

Salad is on the side

> Fruit and salad

Two separate dishes.

Essentially what my gut is telling me is that there is no specific rule for food, and it's based on the reader's experience.

If every time they've read "Salad with/and dressing" and dressing is on the side, then that's what they'll expect.

Moreover: if you can't express an idea without ambiguity in one word, then use more words.

> Green salad with dressing on the side
>
> Dressed green salad (Caesar dressing)

Answer (score 1):

**Tomatoes and garlic** is probably the same as **tomatoes with garlic**.  But if you say **garlic with tomatoes** maybe you are hinting that there is too much garlic.